# How to normalize a list of numbers in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, normalization

What's the most efficient way? (For a huge list of numbers)?
I could not find a solid answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One starts with [`Enum.min_max/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#min_max/2) or [`Enum.min_max_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#min_max/3) if the normalization is somehow custom. Then one just [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#map/2) the original list to the normalized, using values from the step 1.

```rb
input = [1, 5, -2]
{min, max} = Enum.min_max(input)
{new_min, new_max} = {0, 1}
Enum.map(input,
  & new_min+((&1-min)/(max-min)*(new_max-new_min)))
#⇒ [0.42857142857142855, 1.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: with `input = [800, 300, 30]` result is `[1.0, 0.35064935064935066, 0.0]`.  0 is wrong and unacceptable.  Why?

Comment: Why 0 is wrong? Do you have your own notion of normalization? Then provide an expected outcome.

Comment: Aha, My bad, I was confused somehow.  Thanks.